# Release of Spring Security SAML

Tags: spring-security, saml, spring-saml

Is there a planned release date for final version 1.0 of [Spring Security SAML](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) module? RC2 has been released a long time ago (March of 2013) and no further RC or final version has been released since then.

Answer (score 0):

There's a 1.0.0 release out there, just the spring-security-saml website is out-dated

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Simon

Comment: The page is now also up to date.